# Why did my C++mprogram stop working after being compiled?

Tags: c++

I'm a computer science student and have been coding with Java for the past year. Now I'm interested in learning C++. The first program that I wanted to code with C++ is an implementation of stack using linked list, which I have coded before using java. I pretty much have no idea what I'm doing and basically just writing what I thought was right until I got no compile error. So I finally did it, my program got no compile error, but when I ran it, a pop-up appeared saying that my 'Stack.exe has stopped working'

Here's my code:`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack;
class Node;

class Node
{
public:
    string element;
    Node *next;
    Node(string, Node);
};

Node::Node(string element, Node next)
{
    this -> element = element;
    *(this -> next) = next;
}

class Stack
{
private:
    Node *tos;
public:
    Stack()
    {
        tos = NULL;
    }
    void push(string str)
    {
        tos = new Node(str, *tos);
    }
    string peek()
    {
        return tos->element;
    }
    string pop()
    {
        string temp = tos->element;
        tos = (tos->next);
        return temp;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Stack bob;
    bob.push("Wow");
    bob.push("Wiw");
    cout << bob.peek();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I did it like this because this was how I did it with Java.

Thank you :D

Comment: Objects in C++ work in completely different way than they work in Java. Many of those ways have no equivalent in Java. This is one of them, here. Randomly hacking code until it compiles, and expecting it to work, is going to be a waste of time. You need to take a step back, and start learning C++ from the beginning. There are multiple issues with the shown code. It is not possible to adequately explain them without explaining how objects work in C++, and that's a topic for an entire book, and not a brief 400 character comment on stackoverflow.com. Sorry.

Comment: One of many things: C++ has a `delete`, instead of a built-in garbage collector. You need to use it.

Comment: The problem here is not a lack of a `delete` statement, but a lack of fundamental understanding of how classes and class instances (a.k.a. objects) work in C++. The very first thing the shown constructor does is dereference an uninitialized pointer. Kaboom. Undefined behavior. Obviously because "this -> next = next;" didn't compile, and the OP figured out that sticking a dereference operator in front of it makes it compile, so that must be the right thing to do, completely missing the painful fact that the argument to the constructor should obviously be a pointer, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: *I did it like this because this was how I did it with Java.*  -- Do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  That is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

You're dereferencing null or undefined pointers in a couple places.  First let's look at your `Node` constructor:

```
*(this -> next) = next;
```

Since `next` hasn't been defined yet, dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior.  In practice, `next` will point to some random place in memory that you probably don't own, so writing to it will cause a program crash.  Your `Node` constructor should take a pointer to `Node` as its second parameter instead of taking a `Node` by value:

```
Node::Node(string element, Node* next)
    : element{element},
      next{next}
{}
```

Note that I've also initialized `Node`'s members instead of default-initializing them and then assigning to them in the constructor's body.

After fixing `Node`'s constructor, you'll also need to fix `Stack::push` to pass a pointer instead of an object:

```
void push(string str)
{
    tos = new Node(str, tos);
}
```

Note that even after fixing the crashing problem, you'll still leak memory when you `pop` from your `Stack` (or when a `Stack` is destroyed).  You need to `delete` anything you `new`, or better yet use `std::shared_ptr<Node>` instead of raw `Node*`s.